# iOS: Access front camera if screen is locked

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, screen

Does anybody know if it is possible to access the front camera while the screen is locked?

Comment: Nope.  Apple would consider it an invasion of privacy without the user knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to take video in secret.  Just display a fake lock screen while recording video.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, because the app status would be suspended. Camera access is not allowed when an app is not the active, foremost app.